# Redireccionar a error 404 en NODEJS

Tags: nodejs

Tengo el siguiente código en mi servidor de inicio en Nodejs:

```
//ESTABLECER MOTOR DE VISTA PUG
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

//Establece directorio publico ejemplo ej css/js
app.use(express.static('public'));


 //INCLUIR DIRECTORIOS DE SUB - APPS
let app_general = require('./sub_app/general/router');
let login = require('./sub_app/login/router');


//USAR DIRECTORIO DE SUB - APP
app.use('/', app_general);
app.use('/login', login);


//ERROR 404
app.use('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).render('404.pug');
  next();
});
```

Lo que quiero es que cuando escriba una ruta que no existe, en mi navegador me lance el error 404.

Cuando escribo una ruta que no existe me lanza el error, hasta ahí todo bien.

Pero cuando accedo a mi ruta raíz `app.use('/', app_general);` me lanza este error:

```
NodeError: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
code:"ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT"
```

Si quito el extracto de código error 404 funciona bien, ¿de qué otra manera puedo redireccionar a error 404 cuando no existe la ruta ?

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías mostrar lo que tienes en tu módulo `app_general`?

Comment: me suena a que el `next();` está de mas

Answer (score 0):

Veo que no usas un archivo de rutas, y veo tambien que usas otro motor de plantillas. Yo tuve un problema similar, y lo que hice, fue al final de la declaración de la peticiones de rutas, use la siguiente función:

```
app.use(function(req, res){
    res.status(404).render("es/not-found.ejs", { title: "No encontrado" });
});
```

Puedes probarlo y comentas. Saludos!